# Differentiate single Dialogs with DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, interface, dialog, switch-statement

We have two `AlertDialog` objects

```
AlertDialog dialog1, dialog2;
```

both dialogs are created via `AlertDialog.Builder`.
How can we recognize which dialog is source of event in `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` ?

with single dialog we can do this:

```
AlertDialogInstance.setOnClickListener(myListener);

//myListener
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        switch (arg1) {
            case AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                // do something
                break;
            case AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                // do something
                break;
            case AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                // do something
                break;
        }
    }
```

how to modify this `switch` logic to handle multiple dialogs?
(Or if there is better system to handle dialogs, other than inline button callbacks, what is it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll recommend you to put needed param in the custom listener.

```
private class CustomOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private int id;

    public CustomOnClickListener(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //check id and which
        }

}
```

Then, when you add onClickListeners to dialogs, you just provide an id to listener.

Answer (score 4):

```
private AlertDialog dialog1;  
private AlertDialog dialog1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("dialog1").create(); 
        dialog1.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", this);

        dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("dialog2").create(); 
        dialog2.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "NO", this);
    }
@Override
public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which)
{
    if (dialog == dialog1)
    {
        if (which == AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        {
            //
        }
        else if (which == AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        {
            //
        }
    }
    else if (dialog == dialog2)
    {
        if (which == AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        {
            //
        }
        else if (which == AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing objects is worse than comparing integers.

Comment: This is the worst idea. Besides, if you use DialogFragments, you will create the AlertDialogs there, and you don't want your Activity (where your onClick() is) to hold them as fields.

Answer (score 0):

If your dialogs have differentiable content, you can obviously tell the dialog directly by its content:

```
if(which==AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)return;
AlertDialog theDialog = (AlertDialog)dialog;
if(theDialog.findViewById(R.id.phoneinput)!=null) ...;//handle the phone
if(theDialog.findViewById(R.id.emailinput)!=null) ...;//handle the email
```

Of course the solution is NOT universal, but quite handy in some cases.